# Im trying to repeatedly fetch data from a http api and update my SwiftUI view accordingly

Tags: swiftui, httpapi

im trying to fetch some data from a Http Api and use the responded JSON to update the text in my SwiftUI view accordingly

The problem is, that I need to fetch the data two times per second and I don't really know how to refresh my view accordingly.

This is how I fetch the data

```
var timer = Timer()
func scheduleTimer()             
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(fetchData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func fetchData() {
        let url:URL = URL(string: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.23:8085/telemachus/datalink?altitude=v.altitude&longitude=v.long&latitude=v.lat&name=v.name")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error { print(error) }
            guard let data = data else {return}

            do {
                let jsonData = try  JSONDecoder().decode(JsonData.self, from: data)
                let altitude = jsonData.altitude
                print(altitude)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

I used a timer to repeat this action. I also have a Model for the JsonData. 
@EnvironmentObject is not usable in this case because the function is not inside the view.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, This will kill the battery very quick. Also it may kill the bandwidth and the user may be blocked for **too many requests**.

Second of all, you should use `socket` for these kind of requests instead of `restful`.

Third of all your answer:

**Two times per second?** change the `timeInterval` value to `0.5`. This will cause the execution to perform each half of second.

To update **UI**, you need to perform the update code in the main thread using the `GCD` or `Operation queue` like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    /* UI Work Goes Here */
    // for example: myLabel.text = jsonData.altitude
}
```

Comment: I know about the battery drain. The app is more like a personal project for a Kerbal Space Program Nerd, that wants to control his rockets with his iPad xD) The problem I had about updating the UI was that I haven't found out how to do it while the function doesn't run from the view but in the background and I can't access it's variables from said function

Comment: I was asking for a general solution. I don't really have UI Code because I don't know how to deliver data from my function to the view

Comment: I tried using socket but it keeps disconnecting to the Websocket. [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373637/websocket-keeps-disconnecting-starscream)

Comment: I answered there. But that is a different question. Please don't forget to upvote. And accept as answer to **this** question if you find it as an answer. Feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: I though you are looking for *a general solution*. If you need a specific solution, please update your question with the example of the code you tried. I will help surely.

Comment: Oh sorry I tagged swiftUI but then forgot to put it in the title. My problem was that I can't refresh a swiftUI view in DispatchQueue